# How do I define the print size of an InDesign document that has "Intent: Web"?

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, pdf

I have a 70-page InDesign document - a product catalog - that has been made with "Intent: Web" and dimensions 1600 x 900 pixels.

The main target for the document is screen, but we do also want to print a few copies. When the PDF is exported, the size is set to 564,4 x 317,5 millimeters.

We want to print at roughly A4 size. I can't seem to find any setting to allow us to define print size. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more-or-less hidden quirk of InDesign (and all Adobe applications) is that it considers 1 pixel == 1 point. If you export directly to PDF, you'll get a print document that is 1600 points x 900 points.

You can set up an alternate layout that has the page size you need (either within the same document or separately) with all content linked back to your source, so that any changes to the source document are reflected in the alternate. Scale the content to the new size and modify the layout as needed to make it work for A4.

A quick-and-dirty approach would be to export as images (jpeg or png) and change the output resolution in the export dialog so that you get images that will print adequately on A4.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using CC-2014 I would suggest setting the InDesign document up as `print` (A4 document setup):

[image]

after completing your designs I would go to `File > Export` (<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>) and choose a format of `Adobe PDF (Interactive)`:

[image]

then you will be prompted for the settings:

[image]

There are some tutorials on how to [create an interactive PDF](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/how-to/indesign-create-interactive-pdf.html) but you could edit the PDF in Acrobat.  If you decide to build just for the web I would setup the document as such:

[image]

---

If the PDF's are already developed for print I would make sure the text is searchable and if the text is images I would OCR the text:

[image]

[image]

If the text is searchable and just large you could save it out as an optimized PDF within Acrobat:

[image]

This approach will consume resources on your computer so I choose to do this on a server, reference: "[How to reduce pdf filesize?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113544/how-to-reduce-pdf-filesize)"